# Make lists out of column values from one column, filtering on values from another

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like :

```
       Fields   Player bio   Team
0       Name        1        2
1       city        2        2
2       state       1        1
3       stage       0        0
4       effec       2        2
5       points      1        2
```

I would like to make lists named after the variables, containing values from the 'fields' column where the other variable values are 2, excluding the 'field' variable.

so the output would be 2 lists

```
 player_bio = ['city', 'effec']

 team = ['Name', 'city', 'effec', 'points']
```

The actual data has a long list of variables, so I have list such that:

```
 selected_fields = ['Player bio', 'team']
```

I am hoping to loop on this list.

I know we should post our starting attempts, but I haven't got an idea where to start.

Comment: whats the logic here, where `Player bio = 2` then list of Fields else when `Team = 2` list of Fields?

Comment: yes, but the actual data has many more fields so I would like like to use a list on a loop, updated

Comment: I think you need to re-think your question its not very clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
selected_fields = ['Player bio', 'Team']
s = (df==2).T.dot(','+df['Fields']).str.strip(',')\
           .str.split(',').reindex(selected_fields)
s
```

Output:

```
Player bio                  [city, effec]
Team          [Name, city, effec, points]
dtype: object
```

---

Now to see only the 'Player bio' list try this:

```
s['Player bio']
```

Output

```
['city', 'effec']
```

Or

```
s['Team']
```

Output:

```
['Name', 'city', 'effec', 'points']
```

***Details:***

Create a boolean matrix then transpose to perform dot-matrix computation with Fields column.  Next, use string manipulations to strip extra comma and split to create a list of fields.  Outputs a pd.Series with index of 'selected_fields' and values a list.

Comment: thank you, this puts several lists into my console, how can I make it output separate lists per selected field?

Comment: Okay... see update.  The output is a series, then you can an use indexing to retrieve a single is from that pd.Series output.

Comment: oh I see how that was a simple follow up, thank you